# Trace from user space code to kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel, gdb

I recently set up my system for kernel debug using qemu+gdb. At present, I can set breakpoints at, for example, `__do_page_fault()` and trace the call via `gdb` (with `win` command). Now I want the following task: A simple `C` program having a "`hello world`" `printf`statement. Trace the call sequence starting from the userspace down to the `write()` system call ( or anything in the kernel space that is invoked during the execution of that particular userspace program). I want to learn how userspace program traps into system call w.r.t Linux kernel specifically.

Now my doubt is where to set the breakpoint? We have kernel code as well as the `C` code of the program. How to go about this situation ? Please give us an explanation with example.

Thank You !

Comment: if I get it right: you want a complete stack trace user+kernel at some point in kernel space. gdb have no such functionality. To do what you want, gdb should have a knowledge of internal kernel structures to unwind userspace stack for current-> application. But you could write a simple code, which unwinds current user space stack (knowing content of task->ptregs). However there would be a problem with symbols.

Comment: thanks! Are there any other tools that can be used?

Comment: you can play with do_coredump(); to make a core dump for user space application at particular moment.

Answer (score 2):

The most easiest way in my opinion is to separate this into two pieces.

1. Place breakpoint in guest kernel using host gdb.
2. Place breakpoint in user code before trap instruction, using in-guest target gdb, when hit - print stack using target (in-qemu) gdb. You will get user space stack trace.
3. Continue execution in guest gdb
4. In-kernel breakpoint (we have set it at stage 1) will be hit in host gdb. Print kernel stack trace.

P.S.
If your kernel will continuously hit breakpoint (f.e. write syscall is definitely used widely), you can use a conditional breakpoint to hit a breakpoint only with a certain parameters passed.